# How to extract column names of each sheet and output to a new excel workbook using Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have the following code attempt to loop through each sheet of the excel workbook, and return the column names, so that I can **save the outputs to a new workbook with the respective tab names and column names within each worksheet**.

However, it only returns me the tab names in the new workbook and column names are all missing although I specified a loop for it, could someone please advise?

> ```
> from openpyxl import load_workbook
>
> from datetime import date
> import pandas as pd
> from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
> from pandas import ExcelWriter
> #import itertools
>
>
> # Declaring the sheet names within workbook
> sheet_names = ['Input_A','Input_B','Input_C','Input_D']
>
> #Open workbook
> wb = load_workbook('RS_dataset.xlsx', data_only=True)
>
> writer = ExcelWriter('RS_sr_bs_test.xlsx')
>
> # Logic - Open workbook, get sheet name, get all column names within the sheet
>
> for sheet_name in sheet_names:
>
>     # Open workbook and get sheet name
>     ws1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
>
>     # Load datasets within workbook
>     df1 = pd.DataFrame()
>
>     # Define year
>     get_year = date.today().year
>
>     # Get the previous month
>     past = date.today().replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)
>     get_month = past.month
>
>     # Get the current quarter
>     current_date = datetime.now()
>     current_quarter = round((current_date.month - 1) / 3 + 1)
>     get_quarter = current_quarter
>
>     # Create a list to store column_names
>     col_names = []
>
>     for col_name in ws1.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=1, values_only=True):
>             col_names.append(col_name)
>     
>     df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name)
>
> writer.save()
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you already have sheet names, and seems that you are using just a single row for the column names, you can directly read the excel file from pandas and get the required information.

```
df = pd.read_excel('RS_dataset.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
sheet_names = ['Input_A','Input_B','Input_C','Input_D']
for sheet in sheet_names:
    if sheet in df.keys():
        col_names = df[sheet].columns.to_list()

        # you can write the col_names now.
```

Comment: Hi, any reason why I cannot use 

`# Load datasets within workbook
    df1 = pd.DataFrame()` ?

I loaded the code into it but still in my excel workbook it doesn't reflect the column names.. only the sheet names get through the output.